# How to change fragment inside getItem of FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, fragmentpageradapter

I have this code, where I want the first fragment of my FragmentStatePageAdapter(inside a viewpager), to change, depending on some boolean values.

```
inner class MainFragmentAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager) :
        FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return MainView.Fragments.values().size
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> {
                if (booleanOne && !booleanTwo) {
                    FragmentOne.newInstance()
                } else if (booleanTwo && !booleanOne) {
                    FragmentTwo.newInstance()
                } else {
                    FragmentThree.newInstance()
                }
            }
            else -> null
        }
    }
}
```

As of now, the only solution I found, was when I personally knew one of the boolean values changed, I just did something similar to this :

```
   _fragmentAdapter = MainFragmentAdapter(getLifecycleFragmentManager())

   fragmentViewPager.adapter = _fragmentAdapter
```

So I just set the adapter once again, but it seems rather off to me to do this. Can't I force it to just calculate getItem once again?

Comment: Maybe add an `addOnPageChangeListener` and pass something there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your class make these changes, `notifyDataSetChanged()` and then override the `getItemPosition()` which will be called on every notify and then just return the respective constant, `POSITION_NONE` if you want to see new changes or else `POSITION_UNCHANGED`

```
    inner class MainFragmentAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager) :
        FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return MainView.Fragments.values().size
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> {
                if (booleanOne && !booleanTwo) {
                    FragmentOne.newInstance()
                } else if (booleanTwo && !booleanOne) {
                    FragmentTwo.newInstance()
                } else {
                    FragmentThree.newInstance()
                }
               notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else -> null
        }
    }

    override fun getItemPosition(@NonNull `object`: Any): Int {
            // this method will be called for every fragment in the ViewPager
            return if (`object` is FragmentOne) {
                POSITION_UNCHANGED // don't force a reload
            } else {
                // POSITION_NONE means something like: this fragment is no longer valid
                // triggering the ViewPager to re-build the instance of this fragment.
                POSITION_NONE
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: The notifiyDataSetChanged at that part is not possible, seeing it then tries to return Unit.

Comment: The bottom part of the getItemPosition, I'm not quite sure what you mean by that? The default fragment is FragmentThree in this case.

Comment: in getItemPosition it simply checks if you need to referesh the adapter based on some condition so here i am checking if fragment is FragmentOne, you can add your own logic there. and  notifyDataSetChanged will be called in Adapter whenever there is a need to change. like user clicks some button then you want to change that fragment then simpley using the adapter object just call notifyDataSetChanged and in getItemPosition you return the mentioned constants based on some if condition.

Comment: Awesome, so now I've made a simple, shouldUiUpdate boolean, and the parts where i reset the adapter before, I simply set this to true, and in the getItemPosition, i set it to POSITION_NONE if it's true, and then sets it to false again. And it seems to work, thanks dude!

Comment: will you mark this as an answer so that it helps others also? thanks

Comment: Yeah for sure, just had a bit more testing to do to verify it completely :)